# Qlibrary unload dll with carbide/nokia emulator

Tags: qt, qt4, nokia, carbide

I am using carbide and testing with emulator.

Even after my application terminates, the dlls are still loaded on emulator.
How can I forcefully unload them? 
I get a sharing violation if I try to replace them.
Is there any tool to do this?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Does [QLibrary::unload()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.0/qlibrary.html#unload) doesn't working?

Comment: It works but looks the dll is still is still loaded and I cannot replace it.